# How to handle Application Subscriptions for Project and Project Tasks which can overlap each other?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, architecture, subscription, subscriptions

I am building a Project Management application with PHP, JavaScript, and MySQL .  Here are some notes related to my question which is about how to implement a **Subscription** model for users to subscribe to updates when a Project and Project Task record are modified.

**Some notes:**

- Worth mentioning is that GitHub Issues allow you to Subscribe to a project and then on a per issue basis which is a similar model to what I am trying to do except my Issues are Project Tasks.
- Project subscriptions and Project Task Subscriptions would likely have separate database tables.  Not sure yet on the best route to go...

**What a Subscription is:**

- A subscription is a Database record for a User and a Project or Project Task ID.
- When a Project or Project Task record are modified in any way, and alert notice or email is sent to all users who subscribed (have a record in the subscription DB table that match the users ID).
- When you subscribe to a PRoject, you get subscription notices for the project record but also as if you were subscribed to all the Child Task records belong to that Project.

**Methods a user can subscribe to a Project record to receive updates for it and its Child Task records**

1. A user is auto-subscribed to a **Project** record if they **Create the Project record** in which case they are the author/owner.
2. A user is auto-subscribed to a **Project** record if they are **Assigned the Project record**.
3. A user clicks on the **Subscribe Button** on the Project page.  They can also click the **Unsubscribe button* which will be shown if they are subscribed to the project.
   [image]  [image]

---

**Methods a user can subscribe to a Project TASK record to receive updates for it**

1. A user is auto-subscribed to a **Project** record if they **Create the Project record** in which case they are the author/owner.
2. A user is auto-subscribed to a **Project** record if they are **Assigned the Project record**.
3. A user clicks on the **Subscribe Button** on the Project TASK Modal.  They can also click the **Unsubscribe button* which will be shown if they are subscribed to the project task.  [image]  [image]

---

**Some issues to consider in how the subscription system should work:**

1. When you are subscribed to a Project which makes you subscribed to it;s child Tak records as well.  Viewing the Project will show the Unsubscribe button.  When viewing a child Taks record, it;s "Subscribe" button should be disabled or show the typical "Unsubscribe" since you are by default subscribed through the parent Project.  However, subscribing to a Parent Project does not create individual subscription records in the DB for each child Task as I don't think that is a good idea.  Consider when new task are created after you subscribed.  Also the number of records would be huge in this route.
2. Consider you are subscribed to a Task record and then later you subscribe to the parent project.  THe Project makes you subscribed to all its child Task records however you had already gotten a DB record for 1 of the Task records for a per-task basis subscription.  I would assume the Project subscription would simply over-ride the Task subscription record and then if you later un-subscribe from the Project, you would still remain subscribed to the 1 Task record.  Now an unsubscription from the Project I could then auto delete any existing Task subscriptions but it is something to think about.
3. When subscribed to a Project, I don't really see anyway to unsubscribe on a per task basis.  So should I require a user to unsubscribe from the Project to enable per-task subscriptions if they want to not receive notices on some task in a project?

---

**I could use some help in architecting how the subscription flow could work so that users can subscribe to both Projects and on a per project task basis.  Some of my concerns listed above could be addressed please?**

Comment: I'd set up a project_subscriptions table and a task_subscriptions table. Allow task_subscriptions to have "negative" rows - rows that exclude that specific task even if a user is subscribed to its project.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the suggestion.  I like this idea and it solves one of my biggest concerns so thank you!  I have been thinking about how this could work for days now!

Comment: Adding that as an answer, then. Constructive criticism: try narrowing your answer down a bit next time - this was a lot to read for what's at its core a fairly straightforward issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz I might be other-thinking it just wanted to get all the facts out so it might make some sense. That's why I tried to break it up into headings and lists but i'll try better next time. I still don't have my head wrapped around all the possible scenarios but your input helps with a big part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a project_subscriptions table and a task_subscriptions table. Allow task_subscriptions to have both "positive" (user is subscribed to a task in a project they don't subscribe to) and "negative" rows (rows that exclude that specific task even if a user is subscribed to its project).

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to create a single `user_subscriptions` table, which will have `id`, `entity_type`, `entity_id` and `user_id` fields. Otherwise you will have to much duplication in the system.

This will allow you to uniformly work with subscriptions. Whenever a new action, which may result in a subscription-related tasks, is triggered, you should query subscription table for a respected field.

When you send out subscription data, you collect it all from a table and then ensure each user gets only one event notification.

If user is first subscribes for the task and then subscribes for the project, I don't see any reason in removing his task subscription because he can unsubscribe from the project and then simply loose his task subscription. Just ensure a user gets only one subscription per object.

If that is needed, you can relate entity_type ('Project', 'Task' etc) to some 'priority' to define what is parent there and how the notification needs to look like when a user is subscribed to both.